# Content to service via a CDN

Tags: web, cdn

1. Which of these content is usually not very useful to service via a CDN

   - Videos
   - AJAX-requests
   - Images
   - HTML/CSS
   - Videos
   - Edge-Side includes
   - JavaScript

Could someone please provide an answer with explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files, like javascript, html, images, video you can host on a cdn, your ajax requests needs to be processed so you could not host them on a cdn.

CDN, is basically a server where the user can only download your files, the most cdn hosters have multiple servers so its more common that a server is near your user, based on that download speed will be faster.

So if you have static content ( dosnt need to be processed like ajax / api calls ) you can host it on a CDN